# Using Linq2SQL alongside other async APIs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, linq-to-sql

I'm working on an application which uses Linq2SQL for data access, and which is about to start using (completely unrelated) `async` stuff.

An example usage, in this case in an ASP.NET MVC controller action, might be something like this:

```
var db = DataContextManager.Context; // get a context instance which is cached on the 
                                     // request session.

var foo = db.Foos.Where(foo => foo.IsCool).First();

await unrelated.Stuff();

foo.IsCool = false;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Now, I'm aware that Linq2SQL is not generally threadsafe (there's a [wide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23819785/38055) [range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605742/38055) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4918650/38055) about this already), but I'm struggling with understanding whether this will create problems with this usage pattern or not.

A few things to note:

- Each request will have a distinct context instance. This has not created any problems as of now.
- There are also usages where, instead of getting a maybe-cached db context from the request context, we always create a new instance (which is created the same way as the cached one, only new every time).
- There is no instance anywhere of doing `DataContext`-related things in parallel, *unless the framework does that*. In other words, we do everything completely serially (with a few exceptions where we do some parallel stuff without touching Linq2SQL, and then re-join before continuing), but we (of course) do allow e.g. ASP.NET to do serve multiple requests in parallel.

*If* this usage is problematic, what kind of problems should we expect to see? Are there any good rules-of-thumb we can use for how to avoid them, or do we need to completely isolate all async stuff and only use sync methods in conjunction with Linq2SQL? And, maybe most importantly, what kind of tests should we conduct to reproduce the types of problems we might expect to see?

Comment: Are you completely sure it's Linq2SQL and not Entity Framework? Those are very different technologies

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Yes, it's Linq2SQL, not EF. It's an old system :)